# How to write recommendation on Mahout Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, mahout, mahout-recommender

**Mahout 0.13.0 / java 8**

I am completely new in Mahout and trying to understand how to implement recommendation engine using Mahout. So far i know ..

Mahout provides 3 types of filtering -

1. Collaborative filtering (non Hadoop based)
2. Classification (Hadoop based)
3. Clustering (Hadoop based)
4. Content Based filtering

To start implementing my first recommendation, i started with Collaborative filtering which is easy to implement without Hadoop.

Collaborative Filtering -

1. User Based Recommendation
2. Item Based Recommendation
3. Slop one
4. and some more ...

Mahout Interface :

1.DataModel
2. UserSimilarity
3. ItemSimilarity
4. UserNeighborhood
5. Recommender

I understand its component and have written user and item based recommendation using multiple combination of Similarities and neighborhood.

**Question :**

1. Since Collaborative Filtering based on Map-Reduce, Does Mahout deprecate Map-Reduce completely in 0.13.0 release ? Does all collaborative filtering algorithm got deprecated ? What is the alternative then ? Is it Spark because Map-Reduce has slow performance as compared to Spark ?
2. I checked, Mahout provide support with [Spark](https://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html) and [Flink](https://mahout.apache.org/users/flinkbindings/flink-internals.html) as well. Mahout spark provides 2 types of filtering -> **spark item similarity** and **spark row similarity.** But i haven't found any java based example to create recommendation in java.
3. Might be Mahout Spark has better compatibility with Scala but can we write recommendation engine based on spark item similarity and spark row similarity in Java? Suggest some example as well.
4. Mahout Spark can run standalone without Hadoop ? So far i know Spark is an alternative of Hadoop where we can do real time processing. What all libraries i need to add except **mahout-spark_2.10-0.13.0.jar** and **mahout-spark_2.10-0.13.0-dependency-reduced.jar?**
5. Mahout spark is different than standalone Apache Spark? I am thinking to go with standalone Apache Spark as well.

Can someone please clarify me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Map Reduce was deprecated completely in 0.10.0.  The 'new Mahout' is a mathematically expressive Scala DSL that is abstracted away from the engine- e.g. The same Scala code should be able to compile for Flink/Spark/Other Engines.  Yes this was based on performance.

2) There hasn't been a lot of work done with the Java API, however I've heard there are some people working on it.

3.) I think you're asking if you could write a Spark recommendation engine in Java.  The answer is yes. But really, I mean, I haven't done a lot of porting between scala / Java, but in theory you should be able to just import the Scala functions/classes into your Java code?
[This Link](http://mahout.apache.org/docs/0.13.1-SNAPSHOT/tutorials/cco-lastfm/) shows a little more about writing a reccomender from scratch- though it is in Scala, you'd need to port it to Java (if you do that, feel free to open a PR and we'll include it as an example).

4.) Yes, it can.  [This Link](http://mahout.apache.org/docs/0.13.1-SNAPSHOT/tutorials/misc/mahout-in-zeppelin/) described how to set up Spark with Mahout in Zeppelin, but the principals remain the same for any setup (e.g. which jars you need and what `SparkConf` you need to tweak)
iirc, you need mahout-spark, mahout-math, mahout-math-scala. (The spark-dependency-reduced, you only need for using local shell programs, e.g. Zeppelin or the Mahout Spark Shell).

5.) Yes, Mahout is a library that runs on Spark or other distributed engines.

Comment: Thanks @rawkintrevo for your answer. Can you please also let me know is it possible to use Solr as Data Source in Spark ?

Comment: If you write your own recommender you can use anything as a data source and Solr provides a Spark read/write library.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the new recommender Algorithm @rawkintrevo talks about exists in an end-to-end turnkey system based on Apache PredictionIO called the Universal Recommender. PIO comes with a Java SDK. Some links:

- The [Universal Recommender project](https://github.com/actionml/universal-recommender) on Github
- Docs for the [integrated UR](http://actionml.com/docs/ur)
- Various [installation instructions](http://actionml.com/docs/pio_by_actionml), notice that there is [an AWS AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01N310FF0) pre-installed and configured to experiment with. Some of the other how-tos show how to make more scalable deployments.
- [Apache PredictionIO docs](http://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/)
- OSS community support for the UR is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/actionml-user), and PIO is [here](http://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/support/).

Apache Mahout, Apache PredictionIO, Spark, and the Universal Recommender are written in Scala. The UR has a port to Java but this is not maintained and isn't really needed since about all the options you might need are exposed as configuration parameters and it is very well documented.

The way you communicate by sending data in real-time and making real-time queries is through simple REST calls or using one the the PIO SDKs, which include Java.

The UR supports user-based, item-based, shopping-cart (item-set based), recommendations based on multi-modal data (using many different user indicators or events). It also supports a rich set of business rules.

No need to write anything but input your data and decide on config, the rest is installation and setup.

Comment: Thanks @pferrel. I have one generic question related to recommendation. In any recommendation framework, do we need to again and again train machine with training data, if yes then what is the point to train machine here. I am assuming once machine mature enough with training set, we can simply ask for new recommendation without training again for certain time of period.

Comment: The model cannot take account of new items added to the catalog unless the model is retrained. In general the training period is proportional to how often the items are added. For News training might be several times per day, for a fixed inventory it might be only as new users are added with variations of taste and so every few months. For a typical E-Commerce recommender it might be once a week to give time for new items to get some interactions (buys, reads, views, etc).